# Bound for specific series of convergent series

Tags: limits-and-convergence

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ we define
$$
a_n^k := n\left( \frac{(n-1)\cdots(n-k)}{n^k} - 1 \right) \ .
$$
Using l'Hospitals rule iteratively for a total of $k-1$ times one can show, that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n^k = -\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I now wish to apply a dominated convergence (or monotonic convergence, but that does not seem possible here) type argument for sums over $k$ and am thus interested in uniform bounds of the form
$$
\sup_{n> k} |a_n^k| \leq C_k
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Even a bound where $C_k \sim k!$ would be very helpful. Does anyone know of such a result or can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: The inequality $1-\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-b_i) \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i$ for $b_i \in [0,1]$ (straightforward induction) shows (if applied with $b_i = i/n$) that
$|a_n^k /n | \le \sum_{i=1}^{k} i/n$, so $C_k = k(k+1)/2$ is admissible.

Comment: Thank you! I'm astonished, that a sharp bound is so elegantly provable.